# ToggleButtons in GridView

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to fit each toggle button into each gridview container. Basically with my code all my toggle buttons are trying to fit into one grid view container instead of separated grid view container. Is there any way to mix these two widgets together?

```
GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
            child: ToggleButtons(
              selectedColor: Colors.red,
              isSelected: selected,
              onPressed: onControlPress,
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(Icons.info),
                Icon(Icons.title),
                Icon(Icons.info),
                Icon(Icons.info),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: What does "mix these two widgets together" means ?

Comment: Hi Kahou.. It just means to get each togglebuttons child into its own grit view container.

Comment: I see... why put the items in the grid?

Comment: Kahou Because I only need 2 columns and growing rows layout to display bunch of toggle buttons. I could use mixture of Columns and Rows but GridView is way more easier to use with less code for this purpose.

Comment: I think you must customize `GridView`.

Comment: You want each of toggle buttons to be in separate grid cells, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create `ToggleButtons` in each grid :

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var counter = 0;

    return GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        children: [
          Icon(Icons.info),
          Icon(Icons.title),
          Icon(Icons.info),
          Icon(Icons.title)
        ].map((widget) {
          final index = ++counter - 1;

          return ToggleButtons(
            selectedColor: Colors.red,
            isSelected: [selected[index]],
            onPressed: (_) => onControlPress(index),
            children: [widget],
          );
        }).toList());
  }
```

Comment: That is what I was looking for.. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to use [LonelyWolf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11618112/lonelywolf)'s answer with this little twitch to it!

```
GridView.count(
    crossAxisCount: 2,
    children: [
      Icon(Icons.info),
      Icon(Icons.title),
      Icon(Icons.info),
      Icon(Icons.title)
    ].asMap().entries.map((widget) {
      return ToggleButtons(
        selectedColor: Colors.red,
        isSelected: [selected[widget.key]],
        onPressed: (_) => onCapPress(widget.key),
        children: [widget.value],
      );
    }).toList()
```